# A randomly selected number between 1 and 5

Tags: probability

[image: a]

How come $f_X (x)$ is not equal to 1/5? 
Because it should be $f_X (x) = 1/x$ so $f_X (x) = 1/5$ because x is defined on [1,5] right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the length of the interval $[1,5]$ is $4$, not $5$.